# How to join 2 path to get a correct full path?

Tags: php, url

I have a root path which can be defined in a file that inside this path:

```
define('FILE_ROOT', dirname( __FILE__ ) )
This can get an output of D:\xampp\htdocs\library\includes\templates
```

inside this templates directory, there's a folder and its relative path is defined in another software:

```
$file_short_path = 'USERS_DATA/';
```

Now, I want to get the full path. I tried:

```
$file_full_path = FILE_ROOT . $file_short_path
the result is D:\xampp\htdocs\library\includes\templatesUSERS_DATA/
```

if I add '/' after the FILE_ROOT, it becomes a wrong path:

```
$file_full_path = FILE_ROOT . '/' . $file_short_path
D:\xampp\htdocs\library\includes\templates/USERS_DATA/
```

if I add '\' , I got syntax error:

```
$file_full_path = FILE_ROOT . '\' . $file_short_path
```

How can I get the correct file_full_path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to escape the `\`. You can add the `\` twice.

```
$file_full_path = FILE_ROOT . '\\' . $file_short_path
```

Comment: Thanks! It solves the problem at the joint place, but at the ending place, the $file_short_path is ended with a "/" , is that ok?

Comment: @Jenny: That should work However, I recommend using the predefined constant [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) instead.